# MAVEN have different execution for plugin in child modules

Tags: maven, plugins, parent-child

I have a parent pom and childA and childB. The structure is as follows.

```
`parent.xml
    -> childA.xml
       -> childA1.xml 
    -> childB.xml`
```

So, i have defined the plugin in profile, which will be executed in childA and childB. But i need to use the same plugin in childA1 and run different execution. 
is it possible?

OKay i have this profile in parent pom

```
<profile>
        <id>sassConversion</id>
            <build>
        <pluginManagement>
                <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.4.1</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm sass</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install sass</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install gulp sass</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install gulp-sass</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>gulp run sass</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>gulp</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>sass</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
            </build>
        </profile>
```

which i am using in childA and childB like

```
<profile>
        <id>sassConversion</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                       </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
</profile>
```

But in childA1 i am using the same plugin, but it is getting overridden  from the profile.

```
<plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                        <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v10.4.1</nodeVersion>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install node and npm</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm install</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>install</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>npm run build custom elements</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>npm</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <arguments>run build:elements</arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
```

The execution from parent pom is executed in childA1. The defined execution in childA1 is not executed.

Comment: What kind of plugin have you defined in a profile? Why ? What kind of modules are we talking about?

Comment: I have defined frontend-maven-plugin, childA and childB are child modules for parent, and childA1 is the child module for childA

Comment: Can you please setup an example project on github or a like ....or enhance your post here...you can of course define different executions in the different childs/modules ?...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have enhanced the post. Thanks in advance!